# ImageMagick SVG string to PNG

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert an SVG image to a PNG, but I'm getting the error `no decode delegate for this image format ' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/364`. I'm using the following code - is there something obvious that I've missed out?

```
$imagick = new imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob($this->render());
$imagick->setImageFormat("png24");
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

You may notice that I'm passing the `render()` method - which returns the SVG string - into the `readImageBlob()` method.

Comment: Two thoughts. Does your imagemagick install support SVG (e.i. convert existing SVG to PNG)? And does `$this->render()` return a valid SVG format string starting with `<svg`?

Comment: hmm just used the convert command line tool and threw an error : `convert.im6: no images defined `bubble.png'`.

Comment: ...so it turns out I can convert jpgs to pngs but can't do anything with svgs... the plot thickens... next stop: rsvg.

Comment: intalled a package - `sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin` - which enabled me to convert svgs from the command line, but still having the same problem in PHP.